# Problem with Webrick and Postgres when requesting many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, webrick

There seems to be a problem with pages that reques many records (~2,000) from the database. It happens when outputting them to a HTML page or processing them to generate a chart. The page loads, but does not complete loading.

I looked at the config file, but didn't figure out which setting to change. Could it be a data size (memory) or timeout problem? Any suggestions for changing a Webrick or Postgres config setting?

Rails 3.07
Postgres 8.3
Webrick 1.3.1
Ubuntu 11.04

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the weak link is Webrick here. It is very slow by nature. Try using a different server such as passenger.

Comment: Does Passenger do http secure?

Comment: Yes it does as well as anything you'd want in a web server.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was with SSL or the code I was using to get SSL to work with Webrick. I guess Passenger + nginx would be a good alternative.